# Optimize use of seasoning in salty food

Tags: meat, seasoning

How can i optimize the use of seasonings in salty food? When i cook, for ex, chicken breasts, i always put way more pepper and paprika than the original recipe (however, i put the same or an smaller amount of salt) but in a lot of cases, my food comes out tasteless! 
Does the amount of seasoning implies more flavour?
For example, when cooking meat: is it better to add the seasoning when the meat is already at the fire or should i add it before? Does a small amount of salt makes the food be "less tasty"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crickey, where to begin.  Firstly there is a great article [here](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/the-science-of-salt-how-to-bring-out-the-hidden-flavours-in-your-dishes-7897111.html) which will put things far more eloquently than I can.  However, everyone is different.  I assume that you are cooking for yourself/friends/family, and not in a professional setting.  Salt brings out flavors, and unless you actually want to taste salt (for example, crisps), then it should be used solely for that purpose.  I think that maybe you should start using a touch more salt, and go back to your original recipe's other seasoning amounts.  This should help balance things out.  Like a lot of cooking, it is a case of try and try again until you get it right (for you).  have fun!